# How do I speed up the for loop when using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hastily, I once wrote the code for work. It was assumed that it would only need to be run once. But now you have to run it often. The source data unfortunately can not provide because they conferenceline. I am interested in the question, which parts of the code need to be corrected in order to get performance? The current version runs for about 2 hours, running about 25K iterations.

```
dfs = []
for x in tqdm_notebook(range(len(group_furn))):

    good_id = group_furn.iloc[x, 0]

    name_promo = group_furn.iloc[x, 1]

    unique_stores = set(stores.loc[stores.store_type_id != 4]['store_id'].unique()) - \
    set(promo_list.loc[(promo_list['good_id'] == good_id) & \
                       (promo_list['name_promo_mech'] == name_promo)].store_id.unique())

    bu_stores = list(unique_stores.intersection(set(bu_furn.store_id.unique())))

    main_stores = bu_store.loc[(bu_store.store_id.isin(bu_stores)) & (bu_store.store_type_id != 4)].main_store_id.unique()

    df = promo_list.loc[(promo_list.good_id == good_id) & (promo_list.name_promo_mech == name_promo) & 
                         (promo_list.store_id.isin(main_stores))]
    bu = bu_store.loc[bu_store.main_store_id.isin(main_stores)]

    df = pd.merge(df, bu, how='inner', left_on='store_id', right_on='main_store_id')

    dfs.append(df)

    main_stores = bu_store.loc[(bu_store.store_id.isin(bu_stores)) & (bu_store.store_type_id == 4)].main_store_id.unique()

    owners = bu_store.loc[bu_store.main_store_id.isin(main_stores)].main_owner_id.unique()

    df_2 = promo_list.loc[(promo_list.good_id == good_id) & (promo_list.name_promo_mech == name_promo) & 
                         (promo_list.owner_id.isin(owners))]
    bu = bu_store.loc[bu_store.main_store_id.isin(main_stores)]

    df_2 = pd.merge(df_2, bu, how='inner', left_on='store_id', right_on='main_store_id')

    dfs.append(df_2)
```

Comment: This is barely comprehensible Perhaps you could explain what is what.

Comment: Try using a profiler. It can tell you where your bottlenecks are

Comment: Your main issue is using a for loop to begin with.